# Independent Rest API service and Website

Tags: java, angular, maven-3, dropwizard

I have designed a independent Angular 4 application in Node.js and also design a rest api service using dropwizard. I have tried to connect website as static asset for dropwizard service but I could not integrate it properly. I had gone through several links on google, everywhere repeating same thing which I have tried many a times.

One thing I thought of deploying both of these independently but a question rises how?? How can I deploy two thing on server under same domain?

Another thing which can be possible is Integrate Dropwizard with angular app, which I have tried and read many docs. but still If someone can give some sort of link related to creating these in maven is most welcome.

I need some insight regarding this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I deploy two thing on server under same domain?

Deploy them behind a reverse proxy like nginx and use different context paths.

Comment: Is this the only way?? these server seems costly. Can we do this in normal hosting service?

Comment: What is a "normal hosting service"?

Answer (score 1):

You could serve the result of package Angular app as a [Dropwizard asset](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/docs/manual/core.html#serving-assets) 
Then you can call the rest API from Angular.

Remember that Dropwizard is just some code to glue together [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html) (for rest), [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/) (webserver) and [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) (JSON), with the *main purpose* of simplifying configuration.

Comment: I tried to do the same but I could not configure it for running and building angular apps.

Comment: I successfully connected the index.html page and could structure it for the development purpose

Comment: How do you connect the the building process of Angular with dropwizard?

Comment: thats what I am asking how do we do that with proper structuring